# add click event to jquery ui datepicker button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery-ui datepicker as an angular directive as mentioned in
http://www.abequar.net/posts/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs.

The date picker adds a button tag in the run time for the calendar widget. I want to add clcik event to this icon.
I have tried to add the click event to its parent label tag

```html
 <label ng-click="setDate();"><input type="text" date-picker></label>
```

This setDate function is not triggered when clicking on the widget icon, while gets triggered on clicking the input field.

I do not want the onSelect event from the date-picker. I want the click event to fire.

Comment: your preview doesn't show any button or date picker.. try to add a fiddle/update your preview so we can see the issue

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t1qs5h0p/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny http://jsfiddle.net/anthonysubramani/w9fq2x51/1/
I want the click event on the calendar icon